# Нужны ли кавычки - "круглый стол"?

Tags: кавычки

Берутся ли в кавычки слова "круглый стол" - в смысле: собрание людей, обсуждающих ту или иную тему.

Comment: @Якуз, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Кавычки не нужны. См. http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%EA%F0%F3%E3%EB%FB%E9+%F1%F2%EE%EB :

> **круглый стол** *(встреча, заседание)*

Плюс см. это: http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%EA%F0%F3%E3%EB%FB%E9+%F1%F2%EE%EB

и это: http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=kav1

[image]

Comment: Так у вас нормальные слова в кавычках, это как? Нормально?

Comment:  petro. вы имеете в виду слова в скобках? Там кавычки употреблены верно.  Слова, разъясняющие термины, выражения (в значении..., в смысле... и т. п.):
>**См.:Д.Э. Розенталь. Справочник по пунктуации. -М.: ЭКСМО-Пресс, 1998)**:
 В скобках, слова взятые в кавычки, относятся к этому правилу. См.:[
Употребление кавычек ](http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=5.4)

Comment: в кавычки берется иносказание, а точнее расшифровка синонимами, чтоб понятней было, що це таке,  "что это такое"

Comment: толкование. перетолмачивание. перевод. толковать-передать смысл, толк. толкнуть, чтоб в башке что-то закрутилось. Великий и могучий, посмотрите в английском слово беседа.

Comment: для особо непонятливых кавычки - растолковывание.  ка вы чего казали? можно на пальцах.

Comment: petro, я вас не понимаю. Что вы хотите сказать? О слове "беседа'' в английском мне известно.

Comment: Если уж так, с формальных позиций подходить, порьядок(немецкий) и есть порядок, все по полочкам. Есть правило и надо выполнять. Ордунг. Правда русские на этот орднунг чихали. И говорят про круглый стол по умолчанию без кавычек, и так все понятно. без толмачей.
,

Answer (score 0):

В скобках и есть расшифровка синонимами, поэтому и в кавычках. А иносказание здесь - это круглый стол.

Comment: со скобками перебор, и кавычки не там.

Comment: в черном ящике лежало золото. Понимай как знаешь,  то ли он закрыт был "черный", то ли покрашен,  медали или рассыпное?

Comment: Для всех поправок и ответов другим участникам используются **_комментарии_**.